# Hashicorp Vault - Database Secrets Engine Not Visible in UI

Tags: hashicorp-vault

I created a new user in Hashicorp Vault so as to prevent the usage of the root token. The following policy was applied:

```
# Manage auth methods broadly across Vault
path "auth/*" {
capabilities = ["create", "read", "update", "delete", "list"]
}
# Create, update, and delete auth methods
path "sys/auth/*" {
capabilities = ["create", "update", "delete", "sudo"]
}
# List auth methods
path "sys/auth" {
capabilities = ["read"]
}
# Create and manage ACL policies
path "sys/policies/*" {
capabilities = ["create", "read", "update", "delete", "list"]
}
# To list policies - Step 3
path "sys/policies/" {
capabilities = ["list"]
}
# List, create, update, and delete key/value secrets mounted under secret/
path "secret/*" {
capabilities = ["create", "read", "update", "delete", "list"]
}
# List secret/
path "secret/" {
capabilities = ["list"]
}
# Prevent admin users from reading user secrets
# But allow them to create, update, delete, and list them
path "secret/users/*" {
capabilities = ["create", "update", "delete", "list"]
}
# List, create, update, and delete key/value secrets mounted under kv/
path "kv/*" {
capabilities = ["create", "read", "update", "delete", "list"]
}
# List kv/
path "kv/" {
capabilities = ["list"]
}
# Prevent admin users from reading user secrets
# But allow them to create, update, delete, and list them
# Creating and updating are explicitly included here
# Deleting and listing are implied by capabilities given on kv/* which includes kv/delete/users/* and kv/metadata/users/* paths
path "kv/data/users/*" {
capabilities = ["create", "update"]
}
# Active Directory secrets engine
path "ad/*" {
capabilities = ["create", "read", "update", "delete", "list"]
}
# Alicloud secrets engine
path "alicloud/*" {
capabilities = ["create", "read", "update", "delete", "list"]
}
# AWS secrets engine
path "aws/*" {
capabilities = ["create", "read", "update", "delete", "list"]
}
# Azure secrets engine
path "azure/*" {
capabilities = ["create", "read", "update", "delete", "list"]
}
# Google Cloud secrets engine
path "gcp/*" {
capabilities = ["create", "read", "update", "delete", "list"]
}
# Google Cloud KMS secrets engine
path "gcpkms/*" {
capabilities = ["create", "read", "update", "delete", "list"]
}
# Consul secrets engine
path "consul/*" {
capabilities = ["create", "read", "update", "delete", "list"]
}
# Cubbyhole secrets engine
path "cubbyhole/*" {
capabilities = ["create", "read", "update", "delete", "list"]
}
# Database secrets engine
path "database/*" {
capabilities = ["create", "read", "update", "delete", "list"]
}
# Identity secrets engine
path "identity/*" {
capabilities = ["create", "read", "update", "delete", "list"]
}
# PKI secrets engine
path "nomad/*" {
capabilities = ["create", "read", "update", "delete", "list"]
}
# Nomad secrets engine
path "pki/*" {
capabilities = ["create", "read", "update", "delete", "list"]
}
# RabbitMQ secrets engine
path "rabbitmq/*" {
capabilities = ["create", "read", "update", "delete", "list"]
}
# SSH secrets engine
path "ssh/*" {
capabilities = ["create", "read", "update", "delete", "list"]
}
# TOTP secrets engine
path "totp/*" {
capabilities = ["create", "read", "update", "delete", "list"]
}
# Transit secrets engine
path "transit/*" {
capabilities = ["create", "read", "update", "delete", "list"]
}
# Create and manage secrets engines broadly across Vault.
path "sys/mounts/*"
{
capabilities = ["create", "read", "update", "delete", "list"]
}
# List sys/mounts/
path "sys/mounts" {
capabilities = ["create", "read", "update", "delete", "list"]
}
# Check token capabilities
path "sys/capabilities" {
capabilities = ["create", "update"]
}
# Check token accessor capabilities
path "sys/capabilities-accessor" {
capabilities = ["create", "update"]
}
# Check token's own capabilities
path "sys/capabilities-self" {
capabilities = ["create", "update"]
}
# Audit hash
path "sys/audit-hash" {
capabilities = ["create", "update"]
}
# Health checks
path "sys/health" {
capabilities = ["read"]
}
# Host info
path "sys/host-info" {
capabilities = ["read"]
}
# Key Status
path "sys/key-status" {
capabilities = ["read"]
}
# Leader
path "sys/leader" {
capabilities = ["read"]
}
# Plugins catalog
path "sys/plugins/catalog/*" {
capabilities = ["create", "read", "update", "delete", "list"]
}
# List sys/plugins/catalog
path "sys/plugins/catalog" {
capabilities = ["read"]
}
# Read system configuration state
path "sys/config/state/sanitized" {
capabilities = ["read"]
}
# Use system tools
path "sys/tools/*" {
capabilities = ["create", "update"]
}
# Generate OpenAPI docs
path "sys/internal/specs/openapi" {
capabilities = ["read"]
}
# Lookup leases
path "sys/leases/lookup" {
capabilities = ["create", "update"]
}
# Renew leases
path "sys/leases/renew" {
capabilities = ["create", "update"]
}
# Revoke leases
path "sys/leases/revoke" {
capabilities = ["create", "update"]
}
# Tidy leases
path "sys/leases/tidy" {
capabilities = ["create", "update"]
}
# Telemetry
path "sys/metrics" {
capabilities = ["read"]
}
# Seal Vault
path "sys/seal" {
capabilities = ["create", "update", "sudo"]
}
# Unseal Vault
path "sys/unseal" {
capabilities = ["create", "update", "sudo"]
}
# Step Down
path "sys/step-down" {
capabilities = ["create", "update", "sudo"]
}
# Wrapping
path "sys/wrapping/*" {
capabilities = ["create", "update"]
}
## Enterprise Features
# Manage license
path "sys/license" {
capabilities = ["create", "read", "update"]
}
# Use control groups
path "sys/control-group/*" {
capabilities = ["create", "read", "update", "delete", "list"]
}
# MFA
path "sys/mfa/*" {
capabilities = ["create", "read", "update", "delete", "list"]
}
# List MFA
path "sys/mfa/" {
capabilities = ["list"]
}
# Namespaces
path "sys/namespaces/*" {
capabilities = ["create", "read", "update", "delete", "list"]
}
# List sys/namespaces
path "sys/namespaces/" {
capabilities = ["list"]
}
# Replication
path "sys/replication/*" {
capabilities = ["create", "read", "update", "delete", "list"]
}
# Seal Wrap
path "sys/sealwrap/rewrap" {
capabilities = ["create", "read", "update"]
}
# KMIP secrets engine
path "kmip/*" {
capabilities = ["create", "read", "update", "delete", "list"]
}
```

Using the token of that user, I was able to successfully create a database secrets engine.

```
curl --header "X-Vault-Token: xxxx" --request POST --data '{"type":"database"}' {VAULT_URL}/v1/sys/mounts/xxxx
```

However, when logging in to the UI using the same user that created it, it does not appear in the list. However, logging in with the root token, it is visible.

Is there something I'm missing here? Trying to list the mounts using the API shows the created secrets engine too.

Comment: Is this token created with the default policy attached?

You might need this 
`rule {
    path         = "/sys/internal/ui/mounts"
    capabilities = ["read", "list"]
    description  = "Read special mount for UI"
  }
`

from https://www.vaultproject.io/api-docs/system/internal-ui-mounts

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Besides granting the read and list capabilities on /sys/internal/ui/mounts to the identity logging in to the UI, you need to set "listing_visibility" to unauth on every secrete engine you want to start showing up in web-ui.
So, granting the mentioned read+list capabilities:

```
path "/sys/internal/ui/mounts"
{
  capabilities = ["read","list"]
}
```

And then:

```
$ vault write /sys/mounts/database/tune listing_visibility=unauth
Success! Data written to: sys/mounts/database/tune
$ vault read /sys/mounts/database/tune
Key                   Value
---                   -----
default_lease_ttl     768h
description           n/a
force_no_cache        false
listing_visibility    unauth
max_lease_ttl         768h
$
```

I had to repeat this for every secret engine enabled (vault secrets list) for my secret engines to finally show-up in the web ui.
I went the same path as you, that is I first enabled the secrets engine from the command-line using root token, and then decided to switch to a non-root user.

This behaviour is sparsely documented here [sys/mounts documentation](https://www.vaultproject.io/api-docs/system/mounts#listing_visibility-1)

Comment: This way each user can see all secrets engines..